# Django order_with_respect_to reverse foreign_key

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I got troubles on CBW with Django 1.8. I use CBW, and if possible I'd like to avoid using views at all. But I'm stuck in a attempt to order the results I have with default queries.

so, more infos and the example : working on django 1.8.3

Got a few models, bands, that can go touring on events, in different venues

myapp/models.py >

```
from django.db import models

class Band(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class Venue(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
  class Meta:
    order_with_respect_to = 'VenueEvents'

class Event(models.Model):
  datetime = models.DateTimeField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
  venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, trough='VenueEvents')
  band = models.ForeignKey(Band)
  class Meta:
    ordering ['venue', 'datetime']
```

myapp/view.py >

```
#Empty
```

myapp/url.py >

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from myapp.models import Band

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^bands/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', DetailView.as_view(model=Band), name='venue')
```

and then the template file directly :

template/myapp/venue_detail.html >

```
<html><body><ul><li>
{{ band.name }}
{% for event in band.event_set.all %}
  {% ifchanged event.venue %}
    {% if not forloop.first %}
      </li><li>
    {% endif %}
    {{ event.datetime }}
  {% endif %}
  {{ event.name }}
{% endfor %}
</li></ul></body></html>
```

I want on that page to have all the venues a band toured at listed, and I want them ordered by *event_set.datetime*. Meaning the first Venue listed is the one where they last played at.

I tryied a few different things, all not working :

- adding *through* parameters to the ForeignKey. did not work
- trying to stick the logic in the template. did not work (and who would do that ? )
- having in Venue : ordering ['event_set']

So, I'd really like to have a solution with no view.py, but only if it is possible. So, what would be the best idea to solve this ?

- Maybe is there a simple way to add a new table to help me order those things ?
- Maybe can i add a method on my class Venue that would accept a band as argument and would be the thing i can order at, except django doesn't allow to order thing by a method.
- Maybe I have to override the objects manager to add this possibility, but is there an easy way to do this ?
- Or is just the only solution to skip views-less CBW ?
- Or is there any other solution ?

Comment: Change ordering on Event to have datetime first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using `order_with_respect_to` wrong.
You should probably `order_with_respect_to = 'venue'` on `Event` instead.
Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to to see how it works.